# Trouble with scrollbars and focus

Tags: unity, compiz, mouse, window-manager

In CCSM, I have "click to focus", "raise on focus", and "auto-raise" checked. I have "auto raise delay" 100 and "focus prevention level "Very High"

When I hover my mouse over a window that *does not* have the focus, but *does* have a scroll bar, and I move the scroll wheel on my mouse, the window scroll bar moves up and down, but the focus does not move from the focused window to the window I'm scrolling.

This is bad, because my brain then thinks that window has focus when it does not.  Invariably I will then begin typing, thinking my new window has focus. This can have disastrous results; I've lost folders of email this way.

How do I fix this crazy behavior? I want click to focus for *everything*, including scrolling.

Comment: Well, I think most people (who use Unity or GNOME Shell) are quite used to this behavior, I actually like it very much (and hate when I cannot do it under Windows). I remember that on Xfce by default the third button behaves as you want it.

Comment: I've removed overlay scrollbars, which I have always hated, but that didn't fix the problem.  Looking in to xfce.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best option for your request/issue is to go in **CompizConfig Settings Manager**, select **General Options**, **Focus & Raise Behaviour** tab, and **uncheck** *Click To Focus* and *Auto-Raise* options:

[image: Focus & Raise Behaviour]

If you want that the window in which you go with the mouse to scroll to come on top of the other windows, you can keep **Auto-Raise** checked, but in this case I suggest you to increase the value for *Auto-Raise Deleay* somewhere around 1000.